# чем отличается return от print() в python

Tags: python

Объясните пожалуйста чем отличается return от print() в python

Comment: return Это возврат значения из фукнции, print Это вывод на экран. Они отличаются примерно как картошка и кастрюля.

Answer (score 1):

Возвращает значение из функции.Пример:

```
def f():
    return 10

print(f()-1)
```

> `9`

---

Выводит на экран:

```
def f():
    print("hi")
f()
```

> `hi`

---

```
def f():
    return "hi"

f()
```

> 

---

```
def f():
    return "hi"

print(f())
```

> `hi`

Answer (score 1):

`return` значит что функция что-то возвращает. Это что-то можно потом передавать в другую функцию, или иным образом взаимодействовать. `print` просто что-то печатает, при этом функция будет возвращать `None`. В дальнейшем вы с этим значением никак работать не сможете. Также после выполнения инструкции `return` дальнейший код функции не читается, она всегда заканчивается `return`

```
def foo(x):
    return x**2
    print(x + 1)  #  эта строка кода "не достижима", питон ее даже читать не будет


def bar(x):
    print(x**2)
    # тут можно еще сколько угодно принтов и прочего кода написать


print(foo(3) * 2)  #  18
print(bar(3) * 2)  # ошибка
```